# Java - Get one item from ResponseEntity List

Tags: java, spring, list

My `ResponseEntity` returns a `<List>` , I only want to access one item in the list but the `.getBody()` method returns all the data.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity <List> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, List.class);
LOGGER.info(result.getBody());
```

The result looks something like this:

```
[{name: data, id: data}]
```

I want to get the `id`.How do I return a specific item from the list without using an index.

Comment: You do not want the index, so how do you determine the *specific item*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is
`[{name: data, id: data}]` that means list of object **{name: data, id: data}**.

Now the Java class will

```
public class ResponseItem{

    private String name;
    private int id;

    // getter
    // setter
}
```

Your Rest caller code will like bellow:

```
List<ResponseItem> response=new ArrayList<>();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity <?> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, response.getClass());
LOGGER.info(result.getBody());
```

Now you have the list of items. Just cast the `result.getBody()` with `List<ResponseItem>`. If you want just id then comment out the id field from `ResponseItem` class

```
List<Integer> ids=new ArrayList<>();

        for (ResponseItem item:result
             ) {
            ids.add(item.getId());
        }
```

Now you have only id field into the `ids` list

Hope this will help you

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The body will contain the whole response body, to get a single object, you need to change the service to return only a single object.

If you can't do that, create a simple java stream to return first element.

`yourList.stream().filter(element -> --any condition here if needed--).findFirst().map(item -> item.id).orElse(null)`

To get the list create object with those 2 fields, id and String.

Rest call would be List yourList = asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, YourObject[].class));